# how to get the information from first spinner to second spinner in android?

Tags: android

i have 2 spinners :

FIRST SPINNER :

```
 array_spinner=new String[3];

        array_spinner[0]="Color";

        array_spinner[1]="Model";

        array_spinner[2]="Price";

Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.select);

ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 

array_spinner);

 s.setAdapter(adapter);

SECOND SPINNER :

array_color=new String[3];


        array_color[0]="Black";

        array_color[1]="Pink";

        array_color[2]="Green";

array_model=new String[3];

        array_model[0]="Ipod";

        array_model[1]="mp3";


        array_price=new String[3];

        array_price[0]="1000-2000";

        array_price[1]="3000-4000";


Spinner val=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.select_val);


       ArrayAdapter adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter(this,

       android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array_color);


       val.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

When the user clicks Model in the First Spinner , immediately the Second Spinner should display the models which are in the array_model ... Please Help !!!!

Answer (score 0):

use [setOnItemSelectedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html) for the first spinner. In the onItemSelected() set a new arrayAdapter for the second spinner with the new data set

Answer (score 0):

I think you must put a listener on the spinner.

Then You create the good second spinner.

example :

```
 s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(
            new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(
                        AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                      if(array_spinner[int]=="model"){
                          //Do your second spinner
                      }

                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
```